# Refer to array in custom form validation rule in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, validation

I want to create custom validation rule in CodeIgniter 3 but I want to validate posted array (not a string). In CodeIgniter docs, I saw array are also supported.

HTML:

```
<select name="bonus[]" class="form-control"> ... </select>
<select name="bonus[]" class="form-control"> ... </select>
<select name="bonus[]" class="form-control"> ... </select>
```

VALIDATION:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("bonus[]", "Bonuses", "all_unique");
```

VALIDATION RULE all_unique

```
public function all_unique($array)
{           
    $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('all_unique', '%s are not unique.');

    if(count(array_unique($array))<count($array))
    {
        // Array has duplicates
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        // Array does not have duplicates
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

In general I want to check if selected bonuses are not duplicate. (Number of select bonus fields can vary.)

The problem with this is the value passed to all_unique validation method is passed as a string not as an array, it is the value of the first bonus[] field. How can I validate array of send bonus[].

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**`callback`**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods) in `set_message` to call  `all_unique` function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("bonus[]", "Bonuses", "callback_all_unique");
```

To get array field value inside call back use post method as

```
function all_unique()
{           
    $array = $this->input->post('bonus');// get bonus value
    $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('all_unique', '%s are not unique.');

    if(count(array_unique($array))<count($array))
    {
        // Array has duplicates
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        // Array does not have duplicates
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't mention this. I override ValidationForm library. It this case I think it isn't a problem.

Comment: How you override it??? and validation rule is `is_unique` not `all_unique`

Comment: I mean i create own MY_Form_validation.php file in application/libraries. And my custom validation rules are there.

Comment: okk have you check with `$array = $this->input->post('bonus');` inside your function???

Comment: Yes this works, but i need something more abstract. In example require funcion in CI library works fine with arrays.

Comment: glad to know its working !! read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work